# What is the most efficient process to push YUV texture data onto a GPU in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, h.264

Does anyone know of an efficient way to push 2vuy non-planar data onto a GPU in a way that doesn't require swizzling?

I am grabbing the raw 2vuy data from an h264 video file and successfully loading it into a texture that I map to an an OpenGL object. I notice that my code spends a fair amount of time in `glgProcessPixelsWithProcessor`. My `glTexImage2D` call looks like the following:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE,
    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE, data);
```

Apple says in its OpenGL guide that `GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE`, provides "acceptable" performance (p103), but that

> Note: If your data needs only to be swizzled, `glgProcessPixels` performs the swizzling reasonably fast although not as fast as if the data didn't need swizzling. But non-native data formats are converted one byte at a time and incurs a performance cost that is best to avoid.

I assume that there is some kind of internal format conversion going on the CPU. I noticed in another thread that `glgProcessPixels` is running a block method as well.

Is my path the most efficient? If not, what is?

Comment: Are you asking about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as it stands right now depends on extensions of Apple. I can't tell what's happening inside.

However what I suggest is, that you create three 2D textures, each with exactly one channel, where each texture receives one of the color planes; using independent textures makes supporting chroma subsampling (that 422) simpler.

In a shader you'd then perform the colorspace conversion. When writing down the math I suggest you do this via a contact color space, like XYZ, as this allows you, to take the color profile of the output device into account; ICC profiles provide the conversion data from XYZ color space coordinates to device color space (RGB) coordinates.

Comment: I passing the base address of an OSX CVPixelBufferRef as my data. I can successfully view the frames. I am just trying to pass my 2vuy buffer as simple as possible. I have considered multiple textures and I assume splitting the 2vuy into 3 planes would be faster than the offline conversion the OSX opengl is performing.

Comment: I have a 2vuy buffer which I i think is U Y0 V Y2 (or cb Y0 cr Y1) (according to an apple web posting  https://developer.apple.com/quicktime/icefloe/dispatch019.html). So theoretically I can iterate through my buffer and grab every other byte and have a black and white buffer, that I could pass in as a data source on a texture. Correct?

Comment: I created a Y data buffer and passed in into a 'glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yDATA)'. Theoretically, I should be able to access the red component in my shader, but everything is coming up black.

Comment: I can confirm that the byte order is U Y1 V Y2 as I can make a png from the Y DATA buffer I created, so my challenge at this point is to figure out how to pass the grayscale buffer as a component in a shader texture.

Comment: Did you disable mipmaping? `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);`

Comment: I tried it with and without, but nothing works. When I access my uniform sampler2D texture in my shader, I have no values in my texture.r property. I changed my call to  'glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yDATA)' and I was not able to see any anything either. As I understand this call is saying, take yDATA, interpret it  as monochromatic red, store it in a texture of width and height in an RGBA8 format, correct?

Comment: @kernelK: Yes, but this wastes space. There are single component textures. How about you post your code on pastebin.com so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: @kernelK: I don't see any problem there (I assume you did properly generate texture IDs using glGenTextures). Now the GL_RED texture format has been introduced with OpenGL-3 so you need a OpenGL-3 context to use it; in OpenGL-ES or <=OpenGL-2 you'd use a GL_LUMINANCE texture. I suggest you spam your code with calls to glGetError to find potential problems you may use https://gist.github.com/4144988 for this (use the prefix to indicate where in your programm you're calling it).

Comment: I am going to create some test code to create GL_RED textures to establish any errors.

Comment: Okay, I revisited my code path, and everything I did ended up working correctly. I must have made a mistake, but rewriting my code allowed me to avoid whatever mistake I made. Thanks.